# Issue in Sending Multiple Images to the Server in Android

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, image-capture

This method takes picture and adds it in the list but the issue is `OutOfMemory` Exceptions and all that. I have to send the images to the Server through API. But the pictures are never reaching there. Whenever I close my application the server says the request was in progress. I can't identify the issue.

```
imageCapture.takePicture(getExecutor(), new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                    super.onCaptureSuccess(image);

                    tempheight = image.getHeight();
                    tempwidth = image.getWidth();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

                    byte[] imageData = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(imageData);
                    image.close();
                    buffer.clear();

                    // Create a RequestBody from the captured image data



                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageData);
                    // Prepare a MultipartBody.Part using the RequestBody
                    MultipartBody.Part imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", "image.jpeg", requestFile);

                    //WebApi api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi();

                    collectingImages.add(imagePart);

                }


                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                    super.onError(exception);
                }
            });
public void imageSendingForNavigtion(ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> images, RequestBody height, RequestBody width, RequestBody floor) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "In image sending for navigation method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if (isApiRequestInProgress) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Another Api request in Process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return; // An API request is already in progress, skip capturing this time
        }
        isApiRequestInProgress = true;


            try {

                Toast.makeText(this, images.size()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                WebApi api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi();
                api.frame(images, height, width, floor).enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponseOfFrame>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponseOfFrame> call, Response<ApiResponseOfFrame> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            ApiResponseOfFrame s=response.body();
                            which_objects = s.getCoordinates();

                            ArrayList<Coordinate> screenCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();

                            // Calculate the scaling factors for X and Y coordinates
                            float scaleX = (float) overlayView.getWidth() / tempwidth; // Adjust for screen width
                            float scaleY = (float) overlayView.getHeight() / tempheight;
                            for (Coordinate apiCoordinate : which_objects) {
                                // Map API coordinates to screen coordinates
                                int left = (int) (apiCoordinate.getXmin() * scaleX);
                                int top = (int) (apiCoordinate.getYmin() * scaleY);
                                int right = (int) (apiCoordinate.getXmax() * scaleX);
                                int bottom = (int) (apiCoordinate.getYmax() * scaleY);

                                Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
                                coordinate.setXmax(right);
                                coordinate.setXmin(left);
                                coordinate.setYmax(top);
                                coordinate.setYmin(bottom);
                                coordinate.setDistance(apiCoordinate.getDistance());
                                coordinate.setLabel(apiCoordinate.getLabel());
                                coordinate.setSteps(apiCoordinate.getSteps());
                                coordinate.setPosition(apiCoordinate.getPosition());
                                screenCoordinates.add(coordinate);


                            }

                            which_objects = screenCoordinates;
                            updateOverlay(which_objects);
                            isApiRequestInProgress = false;
                            counter=counter+1;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponseOfFrame> call, Throwable t) {
                        isApiRequestInProgress = false;
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("e", e.getMessage());
            }


    }
```

I have tried writing that buffer into a file and then using the file as a whole but nothing worked.

Comment: "I have tried writing that buffer into a file and then using the file as a whole but nothing worked" -- that is going to be your solution, though. Eventually, you will run out of heap space. So, try that again, and if you run into problems, post a separate Stack Overflow question with the then-current [mcve], and perhaps we can help!